# Can't install Anaconda 2019.10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, anaconda

I'm trying to install Anaconda 2019.10 using commands on the [website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/):

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After a few steps it says:

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/mrag/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/sz97/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/mrag/anaconda3
Unpacking payload...

0%
```

...and then stacked for hours - no progress...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just created my account so can't add a comment to the answer above, but thought I would confirm that Anaconda cannot be installed if you're running on a Linux machine with only one CPU.  The Anaconda bug I found for this is https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9345 although it's closed as fixed even though it does still exist in the current non-mini Anaconda download Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh.

In VMWare, this is solved by shutting the VM down, going to Virtual Machine > Settings > Processors and Memory and selecting 2 or more processor cores.